# Subquery in SELECT: trying to move to main query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, subquery

I have a query with the following structure:

```
SELECT
    PEOPLE.ID,
    (
    SELECT MIN(R.VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY R.DATE_OF_CREATION)
    FROM REFERENCE_NUMBERS R
    WHERE
        R.DELETED IS NULL
        AND R.PERSON_ID(+) = PEOPLE.ID
    ) AS PRIMARY_REFERENCE_NUMBER,
    PEOPLE.NAME,
    PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM
    PEOPLE
WHERE
    PEOPLE.DELETED IS NULL
    AND PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH > TO_DATE('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
```

The point of this is that a person can have multiple reference numbers: however I only want to return one reference number per person, and not multiple lines. So I select the earliest-created reference with the minimum value. I do this with a subquery within the main SELECT clause. The above code works.

I want to see if I can move this to be part of the primary query. Logically, I would have thought that it should be as follows:

```
SELECT
    PEOPLE.ID,
    MIN(R.VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY R.DATE_OF_CREATION),
    PEOPLE.NAME,
    PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH
FROM
    PEOPLE,
    REFERENCE_NUMBERS R
WHERE
    PEOPLE.DELETED IS NULL
    AND PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH > TO_DATE('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
    AND R.DELETED IS NULL
    AND R.PERSON_ID(+) = PEOPLE.ID
```

However I get the error: `ORA-00937: not a single-group function`

According to https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/errors/ora00937.php - I need a GROUP BY statement within the main query. However if I add the line:

```
GROUP BY R.VALUE
```

... then I get the error `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression`

I feel I'm nearly there, but just need some extra guidance. Can someone please help?

**Note:** I am fully aware of the "new" style JOIN syntax, and the tendency for people to advise using this syntax. However I use the "old-style" joins for a reason. The above is simply a minimum verifiable example. My real code is vastly more complex, involving multiple tables joined in complex ways - and the old syntax is more understandable when it comes to that level of complexity. Kindly provide answers in the old-style syntax where possible.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing against having that sub query in your `SELECT`clause. If you want to move it to your `FROM` clause, group by `person_id` in order to get one row per person and use an outer join for people without a reference number.

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  r.primary_reference_number,
  p.name,
  p.date_of_birth
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN
(
  SELECT person_id, MIN(value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY date_of_creation)
    AS primary_reference_number
  FROM reference_numbers
  WHERE deleted IS NULL
  GROUP BY person_id
) r ON r.person_id = p.id
WHERE p.deleted is null
AND p.date_of_birth > date '2000-01-01;
```

You *could* just join every person with all their references instead and only then aggregate the whole mess. This would make the query look simpler, but I don't like this approach. You want one reference number per person, so join one reference number to each person.

Anyway, this would be the way to write such query:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  MIN(r.value) KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY r.date_of_creation)
    AS primary_reference_number,
  p.name,
  p.date_of_birth
FROM people p
LEFT JOIN reference_numbers r ON r.person_id = p.id AND r.deleted IS NULL
WHERE p.deleted is null
AND p.date_of_birth > date '2000-01-01
GROUP BY p.id, p.name, p.date_of_birth;
```

Oracle forces you to name all non-aggregated columns you are selecting in the `GROUP BY` clause. Per SQL standard you'd only need the `people.id` as the other columns are functionally dependent on it, but Oracle doesn't feature this, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks, but please pay attention to my note. I want the old-style join syntax. I can't factor the new-style syntax into my actual code. Also, what if I have a whole bunch of tables? Do I need to list out *every single column from every single table* in the "Group By"?

Comment: Sorry, I really didn't see that. I haven't used the old Oracle outer join syntax for many years for it proved to be hard to read and error-prone again and again. It should be super-easy to get from ANSI joins to that syntax though. Replace `LEFT JOIN` with a comma, move `ON`to `WHERE`, add a `(+)` to columns of the outer-joined table (or derived table) when comparing.

Answer (score 0):

The 2nd column in your query is not falling in sync with the other columns likewise group by other columns could help as below

```
      SELECT
      PEOPLE.ID,
      MIN(R.VALUE) KEEP (DENSE_RANK 
       FIRST ORDER BY 
       R.DATE_OF_CREATION),
         PEOPLE.NAME,
       PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH
     FROM
     PEOPLE P,
    REFERENCE_NUMBERS R
  WHERE
  PEOPLE.DELETED IS NULL
   AND PEOPLE.DATE_OF_BIRTH > 
   TO_DATE('2000-01-01','yyyy-mm-dd')
   AND R.DELETED IS NULL
  AND R.PERSON_ID(+) = PEOPLE.ID
    GROUP BY 
    P.ID, P.NAME, P.DATE_OF_BIRTH
```

Comment: Thanks. But as noted in comments above - does this mean I am required to include *every single column from every single table* in the Group By clause? Because my actual query contains multiple tables and millions of columns...

Comment: It depends upon the column you want to perform aggregation on. Lets say i have 2 ids id 1 and 2 but i have data for these columns as 1,0 : 1,1 so if i want to get the count of 1's values it will be 2 so ill group by 1 to get count as 2 likewise in your case too. As per the rule of group by every column which is in select clause except aggregation column should appear in a group by clause